# How to set BITS data type in SNMPSET command?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, mib, oid

the MIB OID object have data type 'Bits':

```
object_OID
Composed Type: Bits
Base Type: BITS
Access: read-write
Kind: Scalar
SMI Type: OBJECT-TYPE
Value List: 
doc (0)
emta (1)
cpe (2)
```

From MIB description, default is DEFVAL { '00'h }.
I want set value 2 (cpe). 
I tried to set the value with command

```
snmpset -v2c -c public 192.168.100.1  [object_OID] b 2
```

but got

```
Error in packet.
Reason: wrongValue (The set value is illegal or unsupported in some way)
```

tried also

```
snmpset -v2c -c public 192.168.100.1  [object_OID] i 2
```

again error

```
Error in packet.
Reason: wrongType (The set datatype does not match the data type the agent expects)
```

Snmpget against this object returns `Hex-STRING: 00` 
What is proper format to set value 2 for BITS data type?

Answer (score 2):

You're using the correct syntax to set a BITS value. I would hazard a guess that the agent implementation is faulty (i.e. the agent is not following the MIB definition).

Comment: Likely. The enumeration is encoded most-significant-bit-first, and it's easy for an agent to get this wrong. Pretty catastrophic for managers, though.

Comment: OP could try working around it by setting to 64, though.

Answer (score 1):

A correct Syntax for Net-SNMP is:

```
snmpset -v2c -c public 192.168.100.1   $ObjectId   = 'emta cpe'
```

Comment: Is that really true? Can you confirm via Wireshark that it does the right thing?

Comment: Okay I have Wiresharked it and this is right (Net-SNMP does the translation automatically!). Note that on Windows you'll need double quotes, not single quotes, if using the cmd.exe shell.

Answer (score 0):

```
i
INTEGER
u
UNSIGNED
s
STRING
x
HEX STRING
d
DECIMAL STRING
n
NULLOBJ
o
OBJID
t
TIMETICKS
a
IPADDRESS
b
BITS
```

Change the value according to data type

Example for trap IP Change -

```
snmpset -v2c -c private 192.168.0.1  OID  a  '10.12.14.190'
```