# What is HEX STRING representation of BITS datatype?

Tags: string, hex, byte, snmp, data-conversion

How to convert **BITS** datatype to **HEX STRING** datatype? (like `0x80`) What is `HEX STRING` representation of (0), (1), (2) `BITS` respectively?  The DEFVAL is `'00'h`.

```
Composed Type: Bits
Base Type: BITS

Value List: 
large (0)
mid-size (1)
compact (2)
```

Comment: What environment/language is being used here?

Comment: Embedded Linux and SNMP protocol.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set BITS data type in SNMPSET command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25370944/how-to-set-bits-data-type-in-snmpset-command)

Comment: This is not really an SNMP question, I guess. Just do the maths.
It should be noted that there is no "HEX STRING" data type in the SNMP protocol specification. Maybe this is about the output/input formats of the net-snmp commands, like Lex Li's comment suggests.

Comment: @Jolta Then what is the **proper** `input format` for `BITS` data type?

Comment: Are you talking about the net-snmp command suite? 
SNMP is a network protocol and doesn't have an "input format".

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me. If you don't feel the need to clarify it enough to allow people to answer, then I guess you're not all that keen on getting an answer, are you?
If the question does concern the net-snmp command line tools, then I have an answer. But I don't want to post it if the question is about some other tool, because it would be the wrong answer.

Comment: `>But I don't want to post it..` - this answer makes no sense at all.

Comment: If I post the wrong answer, you will downvote it and not accept it. And justifiably so, because it was not a correct answer. That's why I'm trying to make sure I'm understanding your question. Why won't you tell me if you're using the net-snmp command line tools or not?

Comment: Yes, I tried to set with Net-SNMP **snmpset** command line tool, and used **snmpget** tool to query. I tried also different tool [SnmpB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snmpb/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably found the correct syntax for hex and Bits data on the man page of "snmpset":
http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpset.html

So, setting the Bits value large (0) is done like with the syntax

```
snmpset <flags,host etc> <oid> b 0
```

And to set multiple flags, like both mid-size and compact, use

```
snmpset <flags,host etc> <oid> b 1,2
```

The latter syntax is not well-documented, I think. I found it in the mailing list archives for net-snmp.

Like I wrote in the comments, there is no "HEX STRING" datatype in SNMP. If you want to transmit binary data, such as an OCTET STRING value, then you will need to represent it somehow on the command line. Net-snmp provides an input format called "HEX STRING" which will accept hexadecimal input using the following syntax:

```
snmpset <flags,host etc> <oid> x 60
```

Incidentally, "60" in hexadecimal is identical to how SNMP would encode "bits 1,2" (the second and third bits, MSB first).

A description of how SNMP encodes and decodes BITS values is found in RFC1906 section 8. Having that knowledge, you just need to learn how hexadecimal conversion works, which is readily googleable.

Edit: I guess this is what you're looking for:

```
0 -> 0x80
1 -> 0x40
2 -> 0x20
```

This is a bit backwards compared to normal (LSB) byte encoding, but again read RFC1906 for a description of how it works.

It should be noted that if you try to set an OCTET STRING value on a BITS variable, you might expect the SNMP agent return a type error. However, since BITS is just an SMI macro based on the OCTET STRING type, they are actually encoded the same way. So, the agent should happily set the value.

Comment: what will be HEX STRING values for 3,4,5,6,7,8 bits respectively? And also for all range, from 0-8 bits?

Comment: @minto, do you want to learn about how to do math in binary? Check out the Wikipedia page. If you still have more question, please post a new question on SO instead of commenting on old, answered questions.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Counting_in_binary

Comment: I did, but conversion isn't so trivial. It's not a direct conversion, but calculation.

Comment: Then, feel free to post a question about it. But the comments field is not the right place. =)

Comment: Ohh, [done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50586957/javascript-based-octet-strings-to-hex-strings-bits-conversion), I agree here.

Answer (score 1):

With Net-SNMP you don't need to calculate the bit values, you write this to set one or more bits:

```
snmpset -v2c -c public 192.168.100.1   $ObjectId   = "medium compact"
```